# ProgrammaticallyTransfer Data from Infopath to Excel

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, infopath

I'm looking to create some custom code for Infopath (with Visual Studio 2010) to take certain data fields within the form and export them to Excel, mapping this data to the correct cell.  Is there a way to do this?  I've attempted excel services, but it never places the data in the right place (if it gets the data at all).  I've found some information on `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` through some searching... is this what I should use to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have never worked with infopath but I believe you can automate infopath from VS and output the data to Excel using Interop. I can help you with the 2nd part though. See this link. http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/vb-net-and-excel/

Answer (score 0):

Siddharth Rout gave me a great solution here (http://www.siddharthrout.com/vb-dot-net-and-excel/) and it was exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!